# Print byte 2d array as hex string

Tags: java

I want to print 2d byte array as hex values. Currently I am using this piece of code `Arrays.deepToString(bytes)` which print integer values.
`DataTypeConverter` doesn't support 2d array.

Anyone have an idea how to solve this?
btw I am looking for one-liner.

Comment: "btw I am looking for one-liner" Too bad.  I'm almost certain none exist without, at minimum, use of external libraries.

Comment: Write it on multiple lines. Delete carriage returns => one line.

Comment: 1 liner? Try https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/ :P

Comment: In what format should it be printed? All bytes added up, print the array but convert every individual byte to hex etc.?

Comment: @n247s that is correct

Comment: Which one of the 2? All added up, or every value converted?

Comment: I looked up DataTypeConverter, Just loop over the outside array, and pass the inside array to DataTypeConverter, it's not 1 line, so make a util method somewhere, and use that, suddenly it's a 1 liner.

Comment: I want to have same output as deepToString provide, but instead of ints i want hex values. So every byte should be converted to hex.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to replace every byte value to a hex string you could use the following (not tested!)

```
Arrays.deepToString(Arrays.stream(my2dArray).map(i -> DataTypeConverter.printHexBinary(i)).toArray(String[]::new)));
```

I hope this was what you are looking for.